# Fetching Google plus user information

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on  google plus integration in windows phone rt development using WebAuthenticationBroker.

I am successfully login but how i  will get the user information.

Please suggest  me as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people?

Comment: A C# library for Google Plus may be an easier way to integrate that service into your app.  If you wish to not do that, try taking a look at Google Plus's APIs: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/plus/v1/.